# TeamCity integration with Android Lint reports

Tags: android, continuous-integration, teamcity, android-lint

We have `TeamCity` as `CI` server for `Android` projects, of course, we are building it using gradle with lintRelease task.

Gradle's lint task generates `.html` report (for direct viewing by human in browser) and `.xml` for automated reports.

My question is **how to integrate Android Lint's .xml reports with TeamCity** and how to give access to .html report (problem is that it creates folder with .css and images which is not connecting if we are sharing this report as artifact)

Answer (score 1):

Task in TeamCity issue tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-37700

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [Teamcity Reports](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Including+Third-Party+Reports+in+the+Build+Results).

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to created a build step of type "Inspections (IntelliJ IDEA)" that points to a gradle file.